# How to set a default value for props in React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, react-props

I need to know how to set a default value for props to React Native.
I have the following code:

```
<View style={{ ...styles.textBox, ...props.bg }}>
    <Text style={{ ...styles.pretitle, ...props.style }}>{props.pretitle}</Text>
    <Text style={{ ...styles.title, ...props.style2 }}>{props.title}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.introduction}>{{ '', ...props.introduction }}</Text>
</View>
```

If `props.introduction` is `0` I want to set it to empty, like: '', or to have some other value, like: 'Not set'.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can use [defaultProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops) in React

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.fName},{this.props.lName}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


Example.defaultProps = {
    fName: "Hello",
    lName: 'world'
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.